# How to configure correct Spring boot redirection with Nginx?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nginx, redirect

I have the Spring boot 3 application **"my-cool-app"**. It uses Spring security and Thymeleaf. When I test it on my local machine I go to `localhost:8080/my-cool-app/` and everything works fine. Then I deployed it as **my-cool-app.war** file on my server with the external Tomcat 10 installed. The server has several domains and I use Nginx to route the trafic to the correct destination, so all trafic for the **"mycoolapp.com"** domain is routing to the `localhost:8080/my-cool-app/`.
When I type in the browser's address field links like `mycoolapp.com/registration` It works good, but if I click the link on the page for the registration form or the page the redirects me then the URL becomes like `mycoolapp.com/my-cool-app/registration` and I get redirect loop. It adds to the URL adding the app name. I don't know how to change this behaivour

**Nginx config:**

```
#upstream tomcat {
#  server 127.0.0.1:8080 fail_timeout=0;
#}

server {

   #root /var/www/mycoolapp.com/public;
   #index index.html index.htm;

   server_name mycoolapp.com www.mycoolapp.com;

   location / {
       #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  #proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/my-cool-app/;
  #proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;

  include proxy_params;
  proxy_pass http://tomcat/my-cool-app/;
   }

    #listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    #listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycoolapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycoolapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycoolapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mycoolapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.mycoolapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mycoolapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name mycoolapp.com www.mycoolapp.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = mycoolapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

   server_name mycoolapp.com www.mycoolapp.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String test(Model model) {
        if (isAuthenticated()) {
            return "redirect:home";
        }
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login(Model model) {
        if (isAuthenticated()) {
            return "redirect:home";
        }
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/registration")
    public String register(Model model) {
        if (isAuthenticated()) {
            return "redirect:home";
        }
        return "registration";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/create-account")
    public String checkInviteCode(Model model, @RequestParam(name="code", required = true) String code) {
        if (isAuthenticated()) {
            return "redirect:home";
        }
        if (code.equals("hello")) {
            return "registration-form";
        }        
        return "redirect:registration?error";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/create-account")
    public String createAccount(Model model, UserDTO dto) {
        if (isAuthenticated()) {
            return "redirect:home";
        }
        model.addAttribute("error", true);
        model.addAttribute("dto", dto);
                
        return "registration-form";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String error(Model model) {
        return "error";
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "home";
    }

    private boolean isAuthenticated() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null || AnonymousAuthenticationToken.class.
                isAssignableFrom(authentication.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        return authentication.isAuthenticated();
    }

}
```

I tried to use an absolute URL with redirect like `https://mycoolapp.com/registration?error`, but without success. It still adds the app name in the redirect URL link. How can I configure my app for correct redirecting in my case?

ps. I don't want use Nginx to redirect the trafic for `mycoolapp.com/my-cool-app/**` to `mycoolapp.com/`, need to do it with my application